# C ~ Arduino: halt after call to function

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having a hard time debugging this piece of code, and i'm hoping someone can point out where i am making the mistake.

My serial output is:

```
connected
GetData()
got data...
next stage...
```

I've tested with a simple network client that loops sending a hello world, and it works fine. Every time this code halts after attempting to send a value to the `client`. I know that  `getData()` is causing the issue, but i cannot work out why, or how to best resolve it.
(apologies for the code dump, i want to be thorough)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht11.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
dht11 DHT11;
#define DHT11PIN 8

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server(192,168,1,100);
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,50);
EthernetClient client;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int trigPin = 6;
const int echoPinOne = 7;
const int echoPinTwo = 8;
const int echoPinThree = 9;
const int echoPinFour = 10;

void setup() { 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  //Network
 if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("DHCP FAIL");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("connecting");
  connect();  
}

void connect(){ 
    if (client.connect(server, 8080)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("connected");

      client.println("hello server");
      client.println();
      delay(500);
      lcd.clear();
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Connection Failure");
  }
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
   //network
  if(!client.available()){
    Serial.println("lost connection!-restart");
    lcd.println("Disconnection");
    client.stop();
    connect();
  }
  else {
    int inp[5];   
    getData(inp);
    Serial.println("next stage...");
    char *output = (char *) &inp[0];   
    client.println(output);
    client.println("first");    
    Serial.println("sent first...");
    //here repeats the same process for the other sensors - omitted for clear reading 
  }
   //end network
   delay(500);
}

void getData(int *inputBuf){  
  Serial.println("GetData()");
  long durationThree, inchesThree, cmThree = 0;
  long durationOne, inchesOne, cmOne = 0;
  long durationTwo, inchesTwo, cmTwo = 0;
  long durationFour, inchesFour, cmFour = 0;

  //SENSOR ONE
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPinOne, INPUT);
  durationOne = pulseIn(echoPinOne, HIGH);

  delay(100);

  //SENSOR TWO
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPinTwo, INPUT);
  durationTwo = pulseIn(echoPinTwo, HIGH);

  delay(100);

  //SENSOR THREE
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPinThree, INPUT);
  durationThree = pulseIn(echoPinThree, HIGH);

  delay(100);

  //SENSOR FOUR
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPinFour, INPUT);
  durationFour = pulseIn(echoPinFour, HIGH);

  //DISTANCE CALCULATION
  cmOne = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationOne);
  cmTwo = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationTwo);
  cmThree = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationThree);
  cmFour = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationFour);

  //Serial.println("sending...");
  //char *out = (char *) &cmOne;
  //Serial.println(out);
  //client.println(out);
  //Serial.println("sent!");      used this to test - same issue

  Serial.println("got data...");
  inputBuf[0] = cmOne;
  inputBuf[1] = cmTwo;
  inputBuf[2] = cmThree;
  inputBuf[3] = cmFour;

}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, it has too many empty lines one loses track of which line belongs to what block, I cant find any declaration of `inputBuf`.

Comment: amended. sorry, i've been trial & error'ing for the best part of the day, and left a couple parts out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `println()` works, but is suppose it takes a `nul` terminated sequence of bytes, so you need to `nul` terminate the after this declaration

```
int inp[5]
```

add this

```
inp[4] = '\0';
```

or you can add it here

```
inputBuf[0] = cmOne;
inputBuf[1] = cmTwo;
inputBuf[2] = cmThree;
inputBuf[3] = cmFour;
inputBuf[4] = 0; // <--- here
```

Comment: `println()` is pretty versatile, or at least always has been for me. will take types like char, int, string etc

I've tried with your solution however i'm getting the exact same result

Comment: @Simon I didn't notice the `Serial.println()` this is c++ why did you tag c? And also, why are you expecting it to do something after `loop()` do actually have a loop where you call `loop()` again?

Comment: this is arduino, which comprises of c & c++. `loop()` is called repeatedly after `setup()` until power loss or shutdown

Comment: i've also posted this question to the arduino stack exchange page, however its still in beta & i'm sure that this issue is code based, most likely on  attaining data from that function, getData

i can confirm that this is a code issue as extracting the code that gets the data from one sensor, and sending the value directly out work fine.